# Why a Pop Up is not shown when clicked for First Time

Tags: jquery

I have the following in my HTML file 
Which when clicked on the Edit Button , opens up a Pop Up , everything  is working fine

```
<div class="col3 pull-left">
<a  class="btn mini black editscreenT1"  title="Edit FOR T1" data-toggle="modal"   href="#editrespon_popup" ><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
</div>

<div id="editrespon_popup" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="360" style="width:350px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h3>Edit Name</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But When I am trying to do this dynamically as shown , this is not opening PopUP and there are no errorrs under browser console

```
$(document).on("click", ".editscreenT1", function (e)
 {
var html = ' <div id="editrespon_popup" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="360" style="width:350px;">\
        <div class="modal-header">\
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>\
            <h3>Edit Name</h3>\
        </div>\
    </div>';


 $(".editscreenT1").attr("href",html);

    });
```

Why a Pop Up is not shown when clicked for First Time on Edit Button

From second click onwards the popup is being shown on Edit Button

Comment: Here i get no popup http://jsfiddle.net/kxenmycq/

Comment: Since on first click there's no href attribute for the '.editscreent1'. When it gets clicked once the href attribute has some value which is letting the pop-up to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the href attribute of the anchor tag to the DIV structure.

Instead of that, append the pop-up DIV to html body or any other selector where you want it and set the HREF attribute as the selector of the DIV to the anchor.

Please try this out,

```
$(document).on("click", ".editscreenT1", function (e){
var html = ' <div id="editrespon_popup" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="360" style="width:350px;">\
        <div class="modal-header">\
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>\
            <h3>Edit Name</h3>\
        </div>\
    </div>';
$("body").append(html);

$(".editscreenT1").attr("href","#editrespon_popup");
});
```